# ¿Existe un término para designar cuando dos galeones de combate disparan sus cañones a muy corta distancia?

Tags: vocabulario

Seguro que tenéis la imagen en la cabeza, ya que aparecen en muchas películas. Dos galeones (pongamos del S. XVIII) armados con varias líneas de cañones se cruzan uno al lado del otro, disparando todos sus cañones sobre su objetivo a pocos metros de distancia, mientras que este hace lo propio. Me gustaría saber si existe un término adecuado para esta forma de combate que tanto se ve en las películas ambientadas en el siglo XVIII y XIX. No sabría decir si "refriega" sería exacto o existe un término mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las expresiones normales para hablar de disparos desde muy cerca son [a quemarropa](https://dle.rae.es/quemarropa):

> 1. loc. adv. Desde muy cerca. *Los disparos se hicieron a quemarropa.*

y [a bocajarro](https://dle.rae.es/bocajarro)

> 1. loc. adv. A quemarropa, desde muy cerca. *Le disparó a bocajarro.*

Google Books [encuentra algunos libros](https://www.google.de/search?q=barco+disparando+a+quemarropa&hl=en&tbm=bks) que usan "a quemarropa" para hablar de disparos de barcos.

Comment: Me encanta a quemarropa. :)

Comment: La expresión la conozco entre personas, pero con barcos nunca la había oído. Pero sí, parece que hay literatura que lo utiliza.

Comment: @KingMidas ya, yo tampoco la había oído para barcos. Pero no he encontrado nada mejor, y la definición de la RAE no requiere que sea entre personas...

Comment: Probablemente me quedo con bocajarro. A quemarropa me gusta más con personas. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no tengo muy claro a que te refieres, pues en la cuestión que planteas existen errores significativos.
Así dices "*Dos galeones (pongamos del S. XVIII)*", cuando los Galeones son del S. XVI y no del XVIII ó XIX.

En Español existen numerosas formas para este tipo de encuentros, pero dependiendo de su utilización ya sea en un ambiente informal o en una conversación entre amigos es distinto al que hay que tener en cuenta por ejemplo para escribir en un libro ya que el vocabulario que se utilice tiene que tener concordancia.

Para el primer caso, conversación informal entre amigos puedes decir perfectamente y son validos "a quemarropa ó bocajarro", indica cercanía y violencia extrema.

Cuando se escribe para producción hay que tener en cuenta el siglo y las tácticas utilizadas en ese tiempo, pues mientras en el S. XVI y hasta el último tercio del S. XVII el combate puede ser individual cara a cara o frente a frente, a partir de esa época las estrategias y tácticas cambian y se utiliza por ejemplo "la línea de batalla" famosa en las películas que ambientan las batallas del S. XIX.

Sin pretender enrollarme te dejo algunas ideas generales, algunas más poéticas que otras;

- Bocajarro
- Quemarropa
- Andanada
- Abrir fuego frente
- Descarga
- En ristra
- Ráfaga de fuego
- Descarga cerrada
- Descerrajo (Descerrajaron contra..)
- Cargar - (Cargaron contra...)
- Cañoneo a corta distancia
- Batir a corta distancia
- Librar combate
- Tirar a la línea de flotación (al pasar las escuadras de vuelta encontradas).
- Romper el fuego (Cañones de tiro rápido a corta distancia)
- Duelo de cañón
- En sostenida (entre los dos barcos, se sobrentiende que lo que se sostiene es el fuego de cañón).

P.D. Personalmente me inclino por "cañoneo a corta distancia", "romper el fuego" y "sostenida"

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos

Diego M.

Comment: Por la inexactitud histórica no te preocupes, que lo de galeones era un ejemplo. Me interesa el término únicamente. Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

The DLE defines "andanada" as the Spanish equivalent of English "broadside", which is the simultaneous discharge of all the cannons on a side of a ship.

Comment: Broadside can be on a different distances. I am more interested in the destruction that causes two ships fighting in a close range combat. In any case, thanks for your answer.